# How to do an action after the "return" key on keyboard is touched?

Tags: iphone

I have a textField, and I would like to do one

```
[textField setHidden:TRUE];
```

after the return key is pressed on the keyboard. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adopt the `UITextFieldDelegate` method and set yourself as the delegate. Implement `textFieldShouldReturn:` method like this,

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [textField setHidden:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

If you want to do it when the user finishes entering the text, do it in `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method.

Comment: If I used the textFieldDidEndEditing: method, how exactly would it recognize the user finishing entering text?

Comment: The `textField` should `resignFirstResponder` for `textFieldDidEndEditing:` to be called. Generally one does that in the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method. But if one can `resignFirstResponder` of the text field from some other method, then you will not know that if you call the `setHidden:` method in `textFieldShouldReturn:`.

Comment: By the way how to adopt the UITextFieldDelegate method? Having some trouble there... :(

Comment: It's a protocol btw. The interface definition is like this, `@interface ClassName:SuperClassName <comma-separated-protocols>` so if you haven't adopted a protocol yet, add `<UITextFieldDelegate>` to the interface declaration.

Comment: @Matoe Did this help? If it did, you should select it as the answer. If it didn't, let me know how I can help you further on this.

Answer (score 4):

In your .h file:

```
-(IBAction)returnKeyWasHit:(id)sender;
```

In your .m file:

```
-(IBAction)returnKeyWasHit:(id)sender {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    //Other stuff you want to do
}
```

Then just connect this action to your text field's "Did End On Exit" event in interface builder.